# What can I do to prevent the connection to "sleep"

Tags: iphone, ipad, network

My friend has an iPhone and an iPad at home. If the devices stay on for a while, let's say 15 minutes, they become unreachable through messages or FaceTime.

After reviewing all the settings on her router, there is nothing suspect there.

If my friend wakes up one these devices, I see all the suspended messages on my device as being delivered and she sees a torrent of messages arriving one after another.

It is annoying problem.

I suspect, somehow, her router's DHCP or ISP is closing the packet transmission or something, after a while without activity.

I am trying to discover something I can do to keep the IP packets flowing.

I have access to a domain address, so I can create emails. I had this idea of creating a dummy email for her and configure mail to keep checking the email every 15 minutes. That solved the problem partially, but if the connection "sleeps" before the check, the problem returns.

OK I know it will user more battery, but that is not a problem.

I am trying to think about new ideas to use. Like using shortcuts and a timer to ping an address one time, or something.

I could create an app for iOS, if necessary but an app like that cannot stay long in the background.

Any ideas?